# visual studio: get list of NuGet packages updates for solution, in plain text

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

in Visual studio, I can see all the nugets installed in the solution by going to menu:
`Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage Nuget Packages for Solution`.
Then in the Updates tab, I can see, for every nuget installed in the solution, in what project(s) it is installed, what version(s), and the latest available version every NuGet can be updated to.

Is there any way to get all this info in a txt or css file or similar? maybe some console command?

(I can use `get-package` in Package Manager Console and it will give a list of every nuget installed in the solution, its version and the project it is installed, but no the latest available version...)

Comment: Only .NET CLI and new SDK style projects can give you `dotnet-outdated` https://github.com/dotnet-outdated/dotnet-outdated Legacy projects won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you want but it could be helpful. In .NET Core CLI 2.2+, you can run:

```
dotnet list package --outdated
```

This will list projects and any packages that have a newer version available (Installed vs Latest).

If you really wanted that in a txt file you could add  `> myreport.txt` to the above command.